# curl_multi_exec()

Tags: php, libcurl

I dont understand the PHP cURL function `curl_multi_exec()`.

```
int curl_multi_exec(handle h, int running)
```

I went through the PHP manual http://www.php.net but don't understand what the variable running does.

Searched a lot on Google but didn't find the explanation.
Can somebody explain?

Answer (score 4):

Every time you call it, that variable is assigned to tell you whether the op is still running:

```
curl_multi_exec($ch, $running);
```

After that, `$running` is non-zero if the operations are still running.  If so, you will have to call it again (normally in a loop).

Comment: does this operation takes too long? why do i need to put in a loop?

Comment: @lovesh, yes, `curl_multi_exec` is commonly used when you're running multiple curl jobs in parallel.  They can take a while to finish, so you call `curl_multi_exec` repeatedly so curl can update you with the status.  You can also call [`curl_multi_select`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-select.php) if you want to block until one of the requests has made progress.

Comment: It doesn't just tell you if there are operations running, it reports the number of operations which are currently active (not completed). And you should have a blocking call to sleep()/usleep() or curl_multi_select() inside the same loop to avoid slowing your system down too much.